# Issue in CORS in ASP .NET Core - The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm getting the below error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/values/track/?name=name&time=1589425390870' from origin 'http://localhost:23456' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have configured Asp.net core app like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials() ;
            }));


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

**Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Can some one please help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

As error indicates that you configure your app with both `AllowAnyOrigin` and `AllowCredentials` methods, which cause that the CORS service returns an invalid CORS response.

You can modify the code to enable specific origins, like below.

```
builder.WithOrigins("set_specified_origins_here")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
```

For detailed information about "Set the allowed origins", please check following doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.0#set-the-allowed-origins-1

Comment: Fei Han, It worked for me. Really thank you from bottom of my heart :)

Thanks for quick help.